# Are questions about latex/plaster casting/mo(u)lding/modelling on topic?

Tags: support

I didn't see any tags I thought would be relevant when I searched, you see..

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a long-winded answer, but I don't see why not! That's all stuff generally related to art and crafts. If there's not a tag yet, it's just because no one's ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

We don't make tags until we need them for a question and, even then, if they don't have a tag wiki excerpt, the tag will be removed if it's only used on a single question. So, please don't judge us by our tags.

If your question is about something that you considered to fit into "applied arts & crafts", please ask it on the main site. If we determine after the fact that it's off topic, the community will weigh in and close the question.

We're still learning what's on and off topic here, so until we have example questions, we can't really say what's a good fit and what's not!

Comment: When you say "here" do you mean crafts.meta, or crafts main?

Comment: Main. :) I've clarified the answer